# Email field should not return as hyperlink on Visualforce PDF page .

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a Visualforce Pdf page. I am getting the Contact's Email Field on Pdf page from Contact's Email field. This field comes as Hyperlink on my Pdf page. I need Email field not come as HyperLink on Pdf page. Below is my code :

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ContRole.Contact.Email}"/>
```

I am new to salesforce Please suggest me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the tag like:

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!ContRole.Contact.Email}"/>
```

or

```
<apex:outputpanel>{!ContRole.Contact.Email}</apex:outputpanel>
```

If all of these not working, it means the pdf reader automatically changes email into hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Inseted of `<apex:outputText>` use `<apex:outputField>`

So it should be :

```
<apex:outputField value="{!ContRole.Contact.Email}"/>
```

May this will help You !!!

Comment: Thanks for reply , I tried it but also it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using outputLabel tag and it worked for me.

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!Opportunity.test_email__c}"/>
```

Please use this tag instead. Hope it may help.